# Can the oath to the monarch be "honestly" removed in the British Parliament

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-commons, monarchy

In Britain, members of Parliament must swear an [Oath of Allegiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_Allegiance_(United_Kingdom)) to the Queen (or the current Monarch).

Is there a mechanism by which this requirement could be removed? Presumably such a proposition would have to be raised in the Parliament, but to do so would surely break the oath that the member already took while entering.

Comment: Why would removing the oath be disloyal?

Comment: @Caleth "disloyal" may be a strong word for it, but calling for its removal amounts to stating that you wish not to be bound by it and would like to take actions and make decisions which are contrary to it, and therefore is not "being faithful and bearing true allegiance" to her.

Comment: @colmde Calling for the removal of the oath (so that future MPs will not be bound by it) is not the same as saying you are no longer going to be bound by the oath you have already taken.

Comment: @user3153372: Indeed, it doesn't release from the previously-taken oath, but it might be a violation of that previous oath (to install a government that doesn't owe allegiance to the monarch).

Comment: Context: Sinn Fein are not taking the seats they have won, as that would require swearing allegiance to the Queen, which is kind of nonsensical if you want to reunify Ireland.

Comment: Minor quibble - MPs don't have to *swear* an oath, they can instead chose to affirm their loyalty. This provision was bought in to accommodate quakers (who don't swear oaths), but has been extended so anyone can opt to affirm rather than swear (an option many MPs take). Similar provisions exist in the UK in other contexts where you might expect to swear an oath, e.g. juries.

Comment: @SimonRichter it's more complicated than the oath for Sinn Féin TDs - see things like https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/mar/06/sinn-fein-mp-british-parliament-irish-republicans-brexit

Comment: If you're worried about voting to no longer be bound by the oath being somehow a breach of that oath, just make the motion something different: make it so that *new* members don't need to be bound, for example (which achieves the same thing, on a delay), or make it optional.

Comment: A highly related question https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/42890/how-might-the-united-kingdom-become-a-republic/

Answer (score 28):

The reason why parliament members in the United Kingdom must swear allegiance to the monarch is because the parliament decided that. The [Oaths Act 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oaths_Act_1978) mandates who needs to swear what, when and how. It repealed and amended a series of previous oath acts from 1961, 1909, 1888 and 1838.

The parliament could change the oath to the monarch yet again by making yet another oaths act, if they were so inclined. Or even abolish the practice altogether for the next parliament. Whether or not voting for that would be a violation of their oath would be a question each parliament member would have to answer for themselves.

Comment: Quite. It wasn't clear to me, anyway, whether the OQ was interested in the specific wording, or the need for any oath at all. Has anyone heard of a jurisdiction which doesn't require key officials to swear loyalty?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Oaths in republics are pretty different. You do not swear to keep one ruler in place. You swear to adhere to the constitution and the laws but you are free to seek them changed.

Comment: It is worth noting that the 1888 Act followed an [exceptionally high-profile case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Bradlaugh) about someone denied their seat in Parliament over the question of whether they could take the oath (albeit on religious grounds not purely political ones). Parliament did not see any problem in legislating to adjust its own rules at that point.

Comment: Just another comment, though perhaps spuriously related, those who nationalize for UK citizenship must take an oath to the reigning monarch. So having ministers do such is not inconsistent (especially as the vast majority are native-born and thus have likely never done such before). If this rule were to change, it is plausible that the citizenship oath would change soon after, if not along with it. This would surely represent a cultural change as much as a 'political' change.

Comment: @VladimirF That's wholly true and equally beside the point. Different jurisdictions have different wordings but they are all ritual, not magic; they all amount to some kind of "loyal oath" and they all promise some kind of obedience or service to the state or flag, to monarch president or whomever else suits that constitution.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin How is that besides the point if a republican is required to swear allegiance to a monarch? That is **very** different to allegiance to the country. The wording is not a magic ritual, they are actual meaningful words.

Comment: @VladimirF A republican with a problem swearing allegiance to a monarch might try being more practical. The system is as it is and the two ways to change it are from within - in which case, swear and work carefully - or from without - in which case, choose your own rules and take the consequences.

You seem to be going way off topic but here in the UK, the only people I've heard off refusing to take the Loyal Oath were IRA people who seem to have got far more publicity by refusing, than for anything they might have said if they'd taken up their posts.

More…

Comment: … further… If you believe anyone takes literally the specific wording of the oath of allegiance in any given jurisdiction, please name those people.

Otherwise look most obviously at Hollywood, where Lord knows how many people are "sworn in " at umpty levels and clearly, for them, the wording of the oath actually means: "Yeah, OK. I'll do the job."

Comment: … further… Did you notice Colmde made no mention of anything like republicanism? Going sideways like that is both beside the point and way off topic. Even though it was Posted in Politics, whether raising  a proposition for change would break the oath seems to indicate this